# React App: "Module parse failed: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I watched a React.js tutorial and followed through every step, but it seems like I can't even get the first step right.
The tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8) around the 16:10 mark.

The instructions told me to download node.js / npm (my version is 6.13.4), and then run `npm create-react-app (app name here)`. I did it, and then right away tries to run `npm start`. The tutorial had no trouble doing so, but when I did it, it gave me this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js 1:57
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:57)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/Jack/Documents/Jack's Workshop/Coding/react/amogus2/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
```

Forgive me for my ignorance, but I have no idea where to start looking for this error, because I have not done a single thing to modify the template automatically given to me through `create-react-app`.

I tried looking around online for solutions, and found a thing I'm supposed to have called "webpack.config.js", yet it is neither in the root file nor in the ./src file. I searched for the name in the entire project and found *several* types of this config file. I thought the most probably one is in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`.

What do I do to get rid of this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is a webpack error telling you it doesn't have a loader (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) setup to handle a certain file type. create-react-app hides the webpack.config.js file unless you "eject" (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) your app, which you probably don't want to do if you just want to follow the tutorial.

Comment: delete node_modules folder , package-lock.json and type  ***npm install**

Comment: @akhilchoudhary
hey hey hey! Thanks for the reply.

Do you know why I don't have the required loaders, while the person in the tutorial does? I can provide some information if needed

and, I've tried your advice, yet the error still lingers, it seems.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me. I'm using this: https://www.leveluptutorials.com/tutorials/react-for-everyone/getting-started

Comment: Add this dependencies in your projects [https://github.com/bradtraversy/react-crash-2021/blob/master/package.json](https://github.com/bradtraversy/react-crash-2021/blob/master/package.json) or just copy paste package.json file in your project and npm install

Answer (score 3):

change `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"` to `"react-scripts": "4.0.1"` in package.json

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518#issuecomment-775476713

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling through the link posted by @finiteEffort, I came across this comment:

> @fabiangamboa95 This is only a guess, but I see that the path with
> aws's has a single quote in it.
>
> #10964 also has a single quote in the path with a similar error.

So run `pwd` in the root folder of your app. If the path contains a single quote, then you will get this error in > 4.0.1 until the team fixes the issue.

Answer (score -6):

FIXED! Thanks to mister [akhil choudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12039761/akhil-choudhary).

The fix was to replace the given `package.json` file with [this](https://github.com/bradtraversy/react-crash-2021/blob/master/package.json), and you're good to go!

Comment: This worked for me, too. I grabbed the `package.json` file from the tutorial I was working through and re-ran `npm install`.

Comment: Indicate the exact changes you made to your package.json. Everyone has a different set of JS packages and your "this" link is too general can not be copied.

Comment: I agree with @NafiuLawal Please mention the changes.