# Reactjs with @react-pdf build fails: ./node_modules/@react-pdf/png-js/lib/png-js.browser.es.js

Tags: reactjs, build, react-pdfrenderer

There has been no change in code.
The app completed the build successfully yesterday. but today it fails to build

Seems to be some issue with react-pdf dependencies.

./node_modules/@react-pdf/png-js/lib/png-js.browser.es.js 10116:106
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10116:106)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |  */
  |

> function gen_bitlen(s, desc) /*    deflate_state *s;*/ /*    tree_desc *desc;    /* the tree descriptor */*/{
> |   var tree = desc.dyn_tree;
> |   var max_code = desc.max_code;

Node Version: v14.16.0
NPM version: 6.14.11

My package.json details are as follows:

```
{
  "name": "command-center",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.0.11",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.1.5",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "2.1.1",
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "chart.js": "^3.3.0",
    "compressorjs": "^1.0.7",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.11",
    "html-to-image": "^1.6.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-icons-kit": "^2.0.0",
    "react-modern-calendar-datepicker": "^3.1.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-to-print": "^2.12.6",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@react-pdf/font": "2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3143 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Requesting some help on this.

Tried changing the version of react-pdf npm. but it does not help.

Comment: can you try @react-pdf/renderer with 3.0.0 and @react/font with 2.3.0?

Comment: also can you please run the following commands and check once?
"rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json" -- 
"npm cache clean --force"

Answer (score 0):

can you downgrade the react-scripts version to 4.0.1 from 4.0.3. If that doesn't work can you also check it by downgrading the babel version to 7.19.x.

Lot of others posted the similar issues.

[Module parse failed: Unexpected token (257:106) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323826/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-257106-you-may-need-an-appropriate-load) (Please check the comments as well that might the reason)

[React App: "Module parse failed: Unexpected token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271065/react-app-module-parse-failed-unexpected-token)

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518